# i want to reload image as video.i don't want the reloading effect.any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function refreshDarkSky() {
      d = new Date();
                $("#as").attr("src","http://192.168.1.85/cgi-bin/FDStream.cgi?timestamp="+d.getTime()); 
            },100);
        });
  
   

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <iframe id="as" src="http://192.168.1.85/cgi-bin/FDStream.cgi" height=400 width=400></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code i want to load the frame without reloading effect,which causes a white delay background.any suggestions?

Comment: I think that the white delay background is due to the connexion latency..

Comment: no i dont think so because it is locally connected through LAN